# Problems using JMockit with log4j 2.9.0

Tags: java, log4j2, jmockit

I'm trying to use JMockit to test that a certain logging operation takes place:

```
public class LogClass1 {

    public void doLog() {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogClass1.class);
        logger.info("This is a log message for {}", "arg1");
    }
}

public class LogClass1Test {

    @Mocked
    private Logger logger;

    @Tested
    private LogClass1 x;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        x = new LogClass1();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoLog() {
        new Expectations() {
            {
                logger.info("This is a log message for {}", "arg1");
            }
        };
        x.doLog();
    }

}
```

But this results in a "missing 1 invocation to org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger#info" error.

I've done similar mocking with log4j 1.x in the past, and I haven't had this problem.  I'm wondering if there's some issue because log4j 2.x seems to have many more overloads of its `info()` methods.

I tried changing `"arg1"` to `(Object)"arg1"` in the unit test to see if I could get it to match the signature.  This didn't help.

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Logger` is an *interface*, and that `LogClass1` obtains an instance of it through the `LogManager.getLogger` static factory method. So, obviously, it creates an instance of some `Logger` implementation class. And said class is not being mocked in the test.

What the test needs to do is to mock `LogManager`, so it returns the `@Mocked Logger` instance. That is, add a `@Mocked LogManager` field to the test class.

(Also, no need for that `setup` method since `@Tested` creates an instance automatically.)

Comment: OK, I think what hung me up is that it worked in log4j 1.x, but that's because the factory method is in `Logger` which I was already mocking, rather than in a different class.  It works now, thanks!